# Using 'ellipsize' in a TextView and stretch the view ONLY if necessary

Tags: android, android-layout

I have 2 TextViews in a row and 2 requirements:

1) If the first TextView is not too wide, it should look as follows

|[1 text][2 text]               |

2) If the first TextView is too wide, it should look as follows

|[1 text text tex...][2 text]|

The second requirement is simple, you can use android:layout_weight="1", e.g.:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:text="1 text text text text text"
    />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="2 text"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

, but if the first TextView contains a short text, it looks like

|[1 text               ][2 text]|

, which is not acceptable.

So how to satisfy both 1) and 2) requirements at the same time?

Comment: Well, giving the first TextView a weight of 1 will guarantee the result you're getting no matter what, so that's out. Have you tried just setting its width to wrap_content?

Comment: Setting its width to wrap_content without using weight="1" just moves the second TextView out of the screen if the first view is wide enough.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the meantime I found a very simple solution: just set the LinearLayout width to "wrap_content" instead of "fill_parent".

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="WRAP_CONTENT"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:text="1 text text text text text"
    />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="2 text"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do this using layout alone. In order for Android to be able to ellipsize Text1, it has to know the exact width of the `TextView`. You can only do this by either giving it a fixed size or by giving the other views fixed sizes. You don't want to do either of these.

You need to measure the width of the text in each `TextView` **as if it were to be rendered**. Once you know the width that each text will take up, you can then make decisions in code about how to get the layout to do what you want.

Add another `View` to the LinearLayout that has `android:layout_weight="1000"`. This will take up all the unused space if the width of text1 and text2 combined do not exceed the screen width. Now calculate the width of text1 and the width of text2 like this:

```
Rect bounds = new Rect();
Paint textPaint = textView1.getPaint();
textPaint.getTextBounds(text1, 0, text1.length(), bounds);
int widthText1 = bounds.width();
textPaint = textView2.getPaint();
textPaint.getTextBounds(text2, 0, text2.length(), bounds);
int widthText2 = bounds.width();
```

Now you know the width that text1 and text2 would require if they were completely rendered.

```
if (widthText1 + widthText2 > screenWidth) {
    View3.setVisibility(View.GONE); // Don't need View3 as there is no extra space
}
```

In the one case, View3 will take up all the remaining space. In the other case, TextView1 should be ellipsized at the end.

I didn't actually test this, so don't be too hard on me if it doesn't work.

Comment: Well, I had a feeling it cannot be done without coding, but when you use weight="1", android somehow decides it should ellipsize the first text even when the second TextView does not have fixed size. So I thought there should be some way. Anyway, thanks, your code may be helpful!

Comment: The second text does have fixed size in this case because you've used "wrap_content". So the layout engine determines itself how wide the second text is. Then, since the first text is too long, it ellipsizes that one because you've specified that it can shorten it by ellipsizing.

Comment: Nevertheless, it is possible, you just need to use "wrap_content" in parental LinearLayout.