# How to make the ellipsize textview and imageview show correct

Tags: android, android-layout, optimization

I'm working on a layout file. This layout requires that the icons should always after the single line TextView. If the TextView is too long,then the TextView is ellipsize and the icons should be shown.Such as:

situation1: [[textview][icon1][icon2]      ]

situation2: [[textview......][icon1][icon2]].

I have found the similar case in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16574649/using-ellipsize-in-a-textview-and-stretch-the-view-only-if-necessary), but it doesn't work for me.

My current code is something like this:

```
 <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:gravity="left">


            <!-- icon show here -->
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/icons"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|left">

            </LinearLayout>


            <!--text show here-->
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/icons"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:gravity="left"/>



        </RelativeLayout>
```

The LinearLayout is used to add icons when fetch data from server. Android's layout preview is like above situation,but the apk runs on device like this this:

situation1: [      [textview][icon1][icon2]]

situation2: [[textview......][icon1][icon2]].

I'm really confused. Anybody has some ideas about this situation? Thanks in advance.

I found the code works fine after Android 4.3(include 4.3,I haven't test 4.2),it doesn't work below Android 4.3.The reason I think is that different Android systems parse these layout params in different ways.Such as some version think the parent container layout's params is more important than the child view.

Comment: try adding 'android:alignParentLeft="true"' to your textview..

Comment: Then the textview is on the left and the icons is on the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I got my stupid situation.But it works.I will give you code:

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <!--text show here-->
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />


                <!-- icons show here -->
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/icons"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"/>

        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: the outermost LinearLayout is unnecessary

Comment: Are you sure? Then how to make the last `TextView`'s `layout_weight` attribute work?